# After VS Express 30 day trial, Console.WriteLine() stopped working

Tags: c#

A couple of days ago I got the MS message that my Express trial period was over. I set up an MS account, as instructed, and life went on... except for one thing.  The code:

```
Console.WriteLine("...and don't call me Shirley");
```

doesn't work any more.  The console never opens.  It still works fine with `Debug.Print` and `MessageBox.Show()`.  So I add a statement which has worked fine in the past, to make sure I'm not just missing the console:

```
Console.WriteLine("...and don't call me Shirley"); 
Console.ReadKey;
```

and I get this message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll.   Additional information: Cannot read keys
>   when either application does not have a console or when console input
>   has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.

So I try:

```
Console.WriteLine("...and don't call me Shirley"); 
Console.Read;
```

And it's dead.  The console won't open.

Any ideas how I can coerce it to work again?

Comment: Hard to believe, Shirley

Comment: Are you doing it from a non-console application? You should open a console in that case by yourself. It can't be just because you had to register.

Comment: Did you change the application type? If yes, set it back to Console Application

Comment: Side note: not sure why would you use Express instead of VS 2015 Community Edition...

Comment: assuming you meant Console.Read();
also hover over Console to make sure its calling console from System.
and then also try going to build > clean and try recompiling.

Comment: Yes, console app.  No, didn't change.  Regarding Community Edition, I didn't know it existed. I just got started with c# after years with VB. My last VS was 2005 and I don't recall any free-ride editions back then.   So I think  I'm going to start new with Community Edition on a new box I have ready to go, and then move my app over.  I have been bombarded with Windows 10 update solicitations.  Despite always declining, over 15 Gb of new Windows stuff has a appeared on my C drive.  I wonder if there is connection. Or maybe I'm infected despite Norton 360.